# mvc3 search page criteria

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, if-statement

I have a search page with 4 options city , state , year ,school

You put that information in the textbox once you click submit it queries the database to find matching records. This works but i was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing things for example you can search by city,state or school and year but each time I have to do this ...

```
   if(string school == null && int year == null)
{
 // then search for city,state
}
if(string city == null && string state== null)
{
// then search for school, year
}
 else
{
  //  search for city,state,school,year
}
```

as you can see this is only **4 fields** and it becomes tedious searching for each one especially since im planning to add more fields in the future. Is there a way that I can check everything in **1 if statement and if for example the user left city,state empty to just ignore it.**

This is a sample of my city state search

```
 public ActionResult search(string city, string state,string school,int year,int? page)
    {


        ViewBag.city = city;
        ViewBag.state = state;
        ViewBag.year = year;
        ViewBag.school = school;
        int pageSize = 10;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

        if (school == null && year ==null)
        {
  // I would like to put all my variables here and ignore blanks one like

            var article = (from x in db.relistings.OrderByDescending(x => x.relistingID)
                           where x.city == city && x.state == state select x);
            return View(article.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }
```

}